# Express.js post request "Origin null is not allowed" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to post a json data which contains a set of key and values from JavaScript to Express.JS. I've added the cors use as suggested by other post, and also `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`.
When I tested the POST request from Chrome Postman app, it worked perfectly fine. But when I sent the request through a local test web page via Chrome browser, the console outputs
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/submit_project_request.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

My code for Express.JS:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var xmlbuilder = require("xmlbuilder");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cors = require("cors");

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.get('/submit_project_request', function (req, res) {
    var client_org = req.parm("client_org");
});

app.post('/submit_project_request', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
    console.log(req.body.client_org);
    res.contentType("text");
    res.send("data received");
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Please feel free to suggest any improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using the file:// to open your webpage. Use a server to serve your html page so that you see something like localhost:8000/yourpage.html

Also, you don't need the following middleware (if you want to configure the cors module then use the options object like `app.use(cors(options))` see available options [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options)):

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Also you may want to remove the following from your `submit_project_request` route:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
```

Calling `next()` like this is not recommended. In your code it essentially means sending a 404 here. If you intend to do that then use `return next();`

Comment: Hello Lucky Soni, thank you for reply. I tried to access the web page from http://localhost:8080/webpage.html, the server returns a blank page with error saying "cannot GET /webpage.html". Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: make sure that you are running your server on port 8080 and that you have a route handler for 'webpage.html' (if you are using something like node.js for serving HTML). if you are using something like PHP to server the page then make sure that there is a file named 'webpage.html' in the root of the project folder.